# Python Drawing a Circle with X Radius Using Forward()

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

I'm using Python Turtles to draw a circle using `forward()` and `right()`.

I have a `for` loop counting from 0 to 359, and each time it triggers, it moves the turtle forward 1 and right 1.

But the problem is I need specific diameters. I am nearly 100% sure I'll need to use trig, but I've tried to no avail.

I can't figure out the math how to do it. We're supposed to use `forward()` and `right()`, NOT `circle()`.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you show what you have so far?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, a complete circle is 360°, and you are planning on turning 360 times, so each turn should be:

```
right( 360 ° / 360 ), or
right(1)
```

The distance traveled will be one circumference, or π * diameter, so your forward might be:

```
forward( diameter * π / 360 )
```

I haven't tested this yet -- give it a try and see how it works.

Comment: Since this will be an n-gon approximation of a circle, I don't think that movement calculation will work. It should overshoot and start creating an outward spiral. Calculation [here](http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20111114140006AAFyToB) looks promising.

Comment: @Brian - I don't think it will spiral, but rather it will draw an apparent circle that is larger than the actual circle -- but not by much. Here's my test file: http://ideone.com/SQhRNx

Answer (score 3):

Here is a working example:

```
import turtle
import math
def circle(radius):    
    turtle.up()
    # go to (0, radius)
    turtle.goto(0,radius)
    turtle.down()    
    turtle.color("black")
    # number of times the y axis has been crossed
    times_crossed_y = 0
    x_sign = 1.0
    while times_crossed_y <= 1:
        # move by 1/360 circumference
        turtle.forward(2*math.pi*radius/360.0)
        # rotate by one degree (there will be
        # approx. 360 such rotations)
        turtle.right(1.0)
        # we use the copysign function to get the sign
        # of turtle's x coordinate
        x_sign_new = math.copysign(1, turtle.xcor())        
        if(x_sign_new != x_sign):
            times_crossed_y += 1
        x_sign = x_sign_new
    return  
circle(100)
print('finished')
turtle.done()
```

Comment: Draws an excellent circle +1.  I would take `turtle.color("black")` out of this code and let the caller determine the color.  You should comment that this makes the current position is the center of the circle (which is nice) unlike Python's `turtle.circle(100)` so it isn't a direct replacement.

Answer (score 1):

This is one of the exercises in "Think Python," in chapter 4. It really is a horrible exercise to have this early in the book, especially with the "hint" given. I'm using forward and left here, but you can switch left with right.

You should have the polygon function:

```
def polygon(t, length, n):
    for i in range(n):
        bob.fd(length)
        bob.lt(360 / n)
```

Then you create a circle function:

```
def circle(t):
    polygon(t, 1, 360)
```

That will draw a circle, no radius needed. The turtle goes forward 1, then left 1 (360 / 360), 360 times.

Then, if you want to make the circle bigger, you calculate the circumference of the circle. The hint says:

Hint:  figure out the circumference of the circle and make sure that
length * n = circumference.

Ok, so the formula for circumference = 2 * pi * radius. And the hint says length * n = circumference. n = 360 (number of sides/degrees). We have circumference, so we need to solve for length.

So:

```
def circle(t, r):
    circumference = 2 * 3.14 * r
    length = circumference / 360
    polygon(t, length, 360)
```

Now, call the function with whatever radius you want:

```
circle(bob, 200)
```